# is there an easy local install method for civics and all dependent software

Tags: drupal, mysql, installation, php

I'm investigating civicrm for a work use at the ngo where I work.

We don't have in-house It team who can help install it. So I'm trying to do so myself.

I have some experience using Ubuntu and basic command line things, but this is proving to complicated for me.
The problem is I need to install apache and php and mysql before I can install drupal, and only then can I install civicrm. Each element can have its own issues, which I have to research separately. I'm stuck on about step 2 and know I have at least 8 moresteps to follow. I've spent about 20 hours on it.

I guess this is quite a common situation and maybe there is a simple way to do it. Are all the necessary software elements in a package somewhere so that I can download it one go.?

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

a. Use the bitnami package: https://bitnami.com/stack/civicrm

b. Use a CiviCRM hosting provider: https://civicrm.org/providers/hosting

Answer (score 0):

I would also check out buildkit at 
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/README.md